# Creating submit button in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am new in cakephp framework, I wants to know to create a submit button in cakephp-3.0 . Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should read the documentation if you plan on getting further into CakePHP, as this question is perfectly answered there. You can find the documentation [here](http://book.cakephp.org).

But as to your question, you can create a basic form submit button with:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->submit();
?>
```

This should be placed somewhere between your Form->create call and form Form->end call.

You can read more about submit buttons and their creation, and more about the FormHelper in general [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-buttons-and-submit-elements)